# How to use AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS in aws amplify API in ReactJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I have an app in React that uses AWS Amplify' API and Auth. I have configured both API_KEY and `AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS` for access to the API. I have for example a graphql schema like this:

```
type Course @model @auth(rules: [
    # Defaults to use the "owner" field.
    {allow: owner, ownerField: "author", provider: userPools, operations: 
    [read, create, update, delete]},
    # Admin users can access any operation.
    { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },
    # Next allow public access with an API Key
    {allow: public, provider: apiKey, operations: [read]}
    ]){
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    content: String!
    author: String
}
```

I have pushed my changes (`amplify push`) but I get `Not Authorized to access createCourse on type Course` with a user that has successfully logged in via AWS Cognito when I try to create a course:

```
API.graphql({
   query: createCourse,
   variables: {input: {...course}},
   authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
})
```

Extra information:
I am using federated sign-in (Google). A user comes on the site, they signin via Google. The access token is available via: `Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()` but I do not if I have to do anything with this token or it is automatically used in the graphql API call.

Comment: please attach your Course model.

Comment: Sorty it was a typo: Blog => Course.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue but everything seems good! it's enough`{allow: owner, ownerField: "author", provider: userPools, operations: 
    [read, create, update, delete]},`

Comment: maybe your problem is when using API_KEY?

Comment: I have added extra information, maybe you can now see exactly what I am doing. Is the federated sign in the problem? and what can I do to make the returned JWT used for the API access?

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your type definition, you have  `ownerField: "author"` so you should pass Current Authenticated User to input.

```
course= {
        title: "titel...", 
        content: "content...", 
        author:user //Current Authenticated User
         };
```

Get the current authenticated user object

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
       bypassCache: false 
      }).then(user => console.log(user))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```